# Opencart 2.1 Links to admin page dont't work. Auth needed

Tags: hyperlink, opencart, admin, panel

I create a custom page in admin panel and whant's to add "save" button in it. I get link ($save_table_link) to my controller function, that's save data, like so:

```
$this->url->link('module/xml_auto_upload/save_table', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
```

and use it in the view:

```
<form id="form-settings" name="categorys" class="form-horizintal" action="<?php echo $save_table_link?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="pull-right">                        
        <button id="btn-save-table" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="form-settings"> 
            <i class="fa fa-sync-alt"></i>
            Save
        </button>
    </div>

    <label class="control-label" for="xml-file-input">File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="xml" form="form-settings" id="xml-file-input">
</div>
```

I expect that my controller function will execute, but opencart say's me "Invalid token-session. Log in again."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the link for any `admin` module in opencart needs to have `token`. If it doesn't have the `token` it will not recognise the user session, hence you get that error & get logged out.

Try replacing this

`$this->url->link('module/xml_auto_upload/save_table', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)`

to

`$this->url->link('module/xml_auto_upload/save_table', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)`